# Why is this watermark plugin not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this jquery image watermarking plugin not working? I am using the code from the official plugin website..        [from here](http://fmaz.developpez.com/proj/imgwatermark/demo.html)  When i see the source code of the demo website they have used js/jquery-watermarker-0.3.js. but i cannot find this plugin online anywhere? how come this works for them in the demo. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">   
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-watermarker-0.2.js">


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $().ready(function(){
            $('#watermarked').Watermarker({
                watermark_img:      "a.png",
                onChange:           showCoords
            });
        });
        function showCoords(c)
        {
            $('#x').val(c.x);
            $('#y').val(c.y);
            $('#w').val(c.w);
            $('#h').val(c.h);
        };

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.watermark
        {
            border:1px dashed #000;
        }
        img.watermark:hover{
            cursor:move;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="1.jpg" id="watermarked" />

    <form method="post" action="phpScriptToMergeBothImage.php">
        <input type="text" id="x" name="x" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="y" name="y" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="w" name="w" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="h" name="h" value="" />

        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Ok >" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've downloaded the plugin from the site ([here](http://fmaz.developpez.com/proj/imgwatermark/download.html)) and included the scripts in your file. In the code you supplied above, it looks like you should have a folder called 'js' that contains 'jquery.js', 'jquery-1.4.2.min.js', 'jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js' and 'jquery-watermarker-0.2.js'. If this is true, the plug-in is loaded.

Next, make sure that you also have the images '1.jpg' and 'a.png' in your root folder, where '1.jpg' is the background image and 'a.png' is the image you want the watermark to be. If they don't have those names, change the names in the plug-in code to match the name of the images that you're working with.

Comment: I did all this and corrected the error pointed out by @Dennis. still it is just displaying the  1.jpg and the 4 text boxes

Answer (score 1):

Your first line should either be `$(function)` or `$(document).ready(function)`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#watermarked').Watermarker({
        watermark_img:      "a.png",
        onChange:           showCoords
    });
});
```

`$()` Used to return a jQuery collection containing `document` in 1.3.x but this was changed in 1.4 to return an empty collection.

Also, your script tags need to be closed `</script>`

Comment: i used the above mentioned code, closed all the script tags and also included the css file which i dint previously...i dont get the necesarry output. all i get is the 1.jpg and the 4 text boxes

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a JSFiddle only modifying it to put placeholder images - http://jsfiddle.net/Xdj7F/.  Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: I copied the 0.3 plugin from the src from the plugin website...even then im getting the following 2 errors in the console..Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'resizable'        js/jquery-watermarker-0.3.js :92
GET http://mhbsocial.com/crossdomain.xml 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Its now working. Thanks a lot for sticking by and helping me out. I downloaded the jquery plugins from the website src and it is now working. It is because of people like you beginners like us are able to produce working code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A nice watermark plugin can be found [here](http://www.codeitbetter.co.uk/widgets/watermark/).

Simply call it using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#textbox1").WaterMark({
            waterMarkText: "Watermark text"
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="textbox1" />
```

There is also an example for use with textareas there too.

Comment: the link is broken